# Redisの初期化時エラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redis

#### 実現したいこと

`bundle exec rails` でアプリを立ち上げた後、アプリ画面を開くと以下のエラーが出力されるため解決したいです。

#### 前提

Ruby on Railsで作成したアプリのバージョンアップデートを行なっております。
ローカル環境で作成していたため、作成当初の環境がなく最新バージョンをインストールして実装中です。
エラー内容として `:scheme` と `:namespace` がRedis初期化時に渡されるが、
Redis側で認識されないためエラー出力される認識です。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
ArgumentError (unknown keywords: :scheme, :namespace):
  
redis-client (0.14.1) lib/redis_client/config.rb:21:in `initialize'
redis-client (0.14.1) lib/redis_client/config.rb:184:in `initialize'
redis-client (0.14.1) lib/redis_client.rb:143:in `new'
redis-client (0.14.1) lib/redis_client.rb:143:in `config'
redis (5.0.6) lib/redis/client.rb:23:in `config'
redis (5.0.6) lib/redis.rb:157:in `initialize_client'
redis (5.0.6) lib/redis.rb:73:in `initialize'
redis-store (1.9.2) lib/redis/store.rb:17:in `initialize'
redis-store (1.9.2) lib/redis/store/factory.rb:26:in `new'
redis-store (1.9.2) lib/redis/store/factory.rb:26:in `create'
redis-store (1.9.2) lib/redis/store/factory.rb:9:in `create'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/redis/rack/connection.rb:39:in `store'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/redis/rack/connection.rb:24:in `with'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/rack/session/redis.rb:82:in `with'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/rack/session/redis.rb:49:in `block in write_session'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/rack/session/redis.rb:70:in `with_lock'
redis-rack (2.1.4) lib/rack/session/redis.rb:48:in `write_session'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:388:in `commit_session'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:268:in `context'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'
activerecord (7.0.4.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
rollbar (3.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:25:in `block in call'
rollbar (3.4.0) lib/rollbar.rb:145:in `scoped'
rollbar (3.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
rollbar (3.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.4.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.4.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.4.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (7.0.4.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
rack-cors (2.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in `call'
webpacker (5.4.4) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.7.6) lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in `call'
railties (7.0.4.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**該当のソースコード**

```rb
hoge::Application.config.session_store :redis_store,
                                         servers: ["#{ENV['REDIS_URL']}/0/session"],
                                         expire_after: 90.minutes,
                                         key: "_#{Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.downcase}_session",
                                         threadsafe: false
```

#### 試したこと

redis-railsを使用していたが、redis-actionpackに切り替えた
→もちろん何の意味もありませんでした。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョン）**

環境情報
アップデート前
・rails 5.1.6
・redis 5.0.6
・redis-actionpack 5.3.0
・redis-namespace 1.10.0

アップデート後
・ruby 3.2.0
・rails 7.0.4
・redis 5.0.6
・redis-actionpack 5.3.0
・redis-namespace 1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

現時点でRedis5.0系でredis-actionpackが使えないために起きたエラーでした。
installするRedisのバージョンを5.0.6->4.8.1にダウングレードすることで対応しました。

参考：
https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store/pull/359